# How to add many module dependencies in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

If I want to add both `['textAngular']` and `['ngDropdowns ']` to my app. How can I do that? Iv'e tried this but it doesn't work:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['textAngular'], ['ngDropdowns ']);
```

Comment: angular.module('myApp', ['textAngular', 'ngDropdowns ']);

Comment: @ivarni Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't seem to work ether

Comment: Is the space in `'ngDropdowns '` a typo in this post only or also in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, provided that the sources of these modules are loaded

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['textAngular','ngDropdowns ']);
```